# Want to add third columns when using aggregate funtion, that does not come under group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

This is my output after querying
step1 :

```
select customer_id, plan_id, start_date, row_number() over (partition by customer_idorder by plan_id) as row_order
    from f.subscriptions
    where start_date < '2021-01-01'

customer_id plan_id start_date  row_order
1   0   2020-08-01T00:00:00.000Z    1
1   1   2020-08-08T00:00:00.000Z    2
2   0   2020-09-20T00:00:00.000Z    1
2   3   2020-09-27T00:00:00.000Z    2
3   0   2020-01-13T00:00:00.000Z    1
3   1   2020-01-20T00:00:00.000Z    2
4   0   2020-01-17T00:00:00.000Z    1
4   1   2020-01-24T00:00:00.000Z    2
4   4   2020-04-21T00:00:00.000Z    3
5   0   2020-08-03T00:00:00.000Z    1
5   1   2020-08-10T00:00:00.000Z    2
6   0   2020-12-23T00:00:00.000Z    1
6   1   2020-12-30T00:00:00.000Z    2
7   0   2020-02-05T00:00:00.000Z    1
7   1   2020-02-12T00:00:00.000Z    2
7   2   2020-05-22T00:00:00.000Z    3
8   0   2020-06-11T00:00:00.000Z    1
8   1   2020-06-18T00:00:00.000Z    2
8   2   2020-08-03T00:00:00.000Z    3
```

step2 :

```
select customer_id, max(row_order)
from (select customer_id, plan_id, start_date
           , row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by plan_id) as row_order
      from f.subscriptions
      where start_date < '2021-01-01') t1
group by customer_id
```

output :

```
customer_id max
1   2
2   2
3   2
4   3
5   2
6   2
7   3
8   3
```

Now I also want to add column(plan_id) in the second output. How to do that.?

Comment: Sorry it did not get copied well.

Comment: which oan_id you want as arrays max or what else

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the complete row for each customer with the latest `start_date`.  In Postgres, the best method uses `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (customer_id) s.*
from f.subscriptions s
where start_date < '2021-01-01'
order by customer_id start_date desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends ob what you need and want, as there are multiple plans per id

you could also look at many more [aggregation funczions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-aggregate.html)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE subscriptions
>     ("customer_id" int, "plan_id" int, "start_date" TIMESTAMP)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO subscriptions
>     ("customer_id", "plan_id", "start_date")
> VALUES
>     (1, 0, '2020-08-01T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (1, 1, '2020-08-08T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (2, 0, '2020-09-20T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (2, 3, '2020-09-27T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (3, 0, '2020-01-13T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (3, 1, '2020-01-20T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (4, 0, '2020-01-17T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (4, 1, '2020-01-24T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (4, 4, '2020-04-21T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (5, 0, '2020-08-03T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (5, 1, '2020-08-10T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (6, 0, '2020-12-23T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (6, 1, '2020-12-30T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (7, 0, '2020-02-05T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (7, 1, '2020-02-12T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (7, 2, '2020-05-22T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (8, 0, '2020-06-11T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (8, 1, '2020-06-18T00:00:00.000Z'),
>     (8, 2, '2020-08-03T00:00:00.000Z')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> select customer_id, max(plan_id), MAX(start_date), max(row_order)
> from (select customer_id, plan_id, start_date
>            , row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by plan_id) as row_order
>       from subscriptions
>       where start_date < '2021-01-01') t1
> group by customer_id
> ```
>
> ```
> customer_id | max | max                 | max
> ----------: | --: | :------------------ | --:
>           1 |   1 | 2020-08-08 00:00:00 |   2
>           2 |   3 | 2020-09-27 00:00:00 |   2
>           3 |   1 | 2020-01-20 00:00:00 |   2
>           4 |   4 | 2020-04-21 00:00:00 |   3
>           5 |   1 | 2020-08-10 00:00:00 |   2
>           6 |   1 | 2020-12-30 00:00:00 |   2
>           7 |   2 | 2020-05-22 00:00:00 |   3
>           8 |   2 | 2020-08-03 00:00:00 |   3
> ```

> ```
> select customer_id, ARRAY_AGG (plan_id || '-' || start_date), max(row_order)
> from (select customer_id, plan_id, start_date
>            , row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by plan_id) as row_order
>       from subscriptions
>       where start_date < '2021-01-01') t1
> group by customer_id
> ```
>
> ```
> customer_id | array_agg                                                                 | max
> ----------: | :------------------------------------------------------------------------ | --:
>           1 | {"0-2020-08-01 00:00:00","1-2020-08-08 00:00:00"}                         |   2
>           2 | {"0-2020-09-20 00:00:00","3-2020-09-27 00:00:00"}                         |   2
>           3 | {"0-2020-01-13 00:00:00","1-2020-01-20 00:00:00"}                         |   2
>           4 | {"0-2020-01-17 00:00:00","1-2020-01-24 00:00:00","4-2020-04-21 00:00:00"} |   3
>           5 | {"0-2020-08-03 00:00:00","1-2020-08-10 00:00:00"}                         |   2
>           6 | {"0-2020-12-23 00:00:00","1-2020-12-30 00:00:00"}                         |   2
>           7 | {"0-2020-02-05 00:00:00","1-2020-02-12 00:00:00","2-2020-05-22 00:00:00"} |   3
>           8 | {"0-2020-06-11 00:00:00","1-2020-06-18 00:00:00","2-2020-08-03 00:00:00"} |   3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=807cfd6282ccbcf45184a912c7632954)*